# Extract prices from string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I did a google form of items I'm selling, and the form is linked to a
google sheet. I want to extract the prices and add them in a separate column.

[image]

In the entries I have the price and name of the item, but I want to add only the prices
in the next column.

I was using:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT($D2, 4))
```

but that will only extract the price when there is one item.

Any information will be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUM() doesn't care about text so you should be able to do:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(D2," ,$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=sum(split(join("|",REGEXEXTRACT(substitute(A1,"$",""),REGEXREPLACE(substitute(A1,"$",""),"(\d+.\d+)","($1)"))),"|"))
```

Comment: MattKing has a more simple formula!

Comment: Thanks Mike! :D  One of the most reliable differences between words and numbers is that numbers don't have spaces!